# Reaching table variables from tableCell

Tags: iphone

I have TableController class - for controlling the UITableView, and TableCell class - for controlling the custom cell.

Inside each cell i have a button with onTouchInside event.
I want to update some of the variables of the TableController.

The problem :
The variables declared in the TableController class are not known by the TableCell class...

I'm using the Interface Builder, so i have Table.NIB, TableController.h, TableController.m and : TableCell.NIB, TableCell.h, TableCell.m .

If i put the IBAction method that handles the "touch up inside" event code inside the TableController class, How can the event's small circle in the Interface Builder be dragged from the TableController NIB to the TableCell NIB ??

Or should i connect the action to the button'a event programmatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can connect button event like:

```
    [cell.yourButtonName addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and manage action

```
-(IBAction)ButtonAction:(id)sender{
// perform action 
}
```